# SELECT specific characters from column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have column name `BOOKNAME` in `BOOKS` table which can contain many special characters apart from alphanumeric e.g. `',$#()[],`

How can I write a query to show me only special characters in ALL rows and union them e.g.

```
Row number Book name   
1           Alice$inWonder(Land)
2           Tom Harry#$%^& adventures
```

So the query should show output like `$()#%^&`

I tried this but cannot see why it does not show only these characters

```
SELECT replace(BOOKNAME , '%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', '') FROM BOOKS 
WHERE BOOKNAME like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%'
```

Comment: Can we use STUFF, PATINDEX ?

Answer (score 1):

For easiness you can create a user-defined function to select the special characters as below:

**User-defined function : [dbo].[SpecialCharacters]**

```
create Function [dbo].[SpecialCharacters](@res VarChar(1000))
returns varchar(1000)
as
begin

declare @str as varchar(50)
set @str = '%[a-z]%'
while patindex(@str, @res) > 0
set @res = stuff(@res, patindex(@str, @res), 1, '')

return @res
End
```

Then,

```
select '' + stuff((select t.specialchars as specialchars from (
    select replace(dbo.[SpecialCharacters](bookname), ' ', '') as specialchars           
    from books
)t
for xml path, type).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 0, '');
```

**Result**

```
+--------------+
| specialchars |
+--------------+
| $()#$%^&     |
+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using `while loop.`

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @loop INT
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(8000), @output VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @str = 'ab123ce23,4f$e', @output=''
SET @loop = 1
WHILE @loop < LEN(@str)
BEGIN
SET @output=@output+CASE WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@str,@loop,1)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN SUBSTRING(@str,@loop,1) ELSE '' END
SET @loop = @loop + 1
END
SELECT @output
```

courtesy : pinal dave , http://blog.sqlauthority.com

please find the link for the same below

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/08/29/sql-server-remove-all-characters-from-a-string-using-t-sql/

Comment: Wow so many people more intelligent than me :) Good approach man! I will try this solution too

Comment: well this is not my solution. I found it in the above blog. By the way, you can up-vote & mark answer the best solution you got. It will helpful to others who have the same requiement

Comment: I think this is a very clean solution. I will mark it as answer. Thanks to you and pinal dave

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to build regexp-match + regexp-replace CLR functions, but you may also try this old-school approach:

```
;with list as
(
  select 'Alice#wndlnd' as name
  union all
  select 'asdf?!@zz'
  union all
  select 'Regular'
  union all
  select 'last$'
),
list_cleared as
(
  select 
    replace(
      replace(
        replace(
          replace(
            replace(
              replace(
                replace(
                  replace(
                    replace(
                      replace(
                        replace(
                          replace(
                            replace(
                              replace(
                                replace(
                                  replace(
                                    replace(
                                      replace(
                                        replace(
                                          replace(
                                            replace(
                                              replace(
                                                replace(
                                                  replace(
                                                    replace(
                                                      replace(name
                                                        , 'a', '')
                                                      , 'b', '')
                                                    ,'c', '')
                                                  , 'd', '')
                                                , 'e', '')
                                              ,'f', '')
                                            , 'g', '')
                                          , 'h', '')
                                        ,'i', '')
                                      , 'j', '')
                                    , 'k', '')
                                  ,'l', '')
                                ,'m', '')
                              , 'n', '')
                            , 'o', '')
                          ,'p', '')
                        , 'q', '')
                      , 'r', '')
                    ,'s', '')
                  ,'t', '')
                , 'u', '')
              , 'v', '')
            ,'w', '')
          , 'x', '')
        , 'y', '')
      ,'z', '') as spec_chars
  from list
)
select 
  (
    select l.spec_chars
    from list_cleared l
    where l.spec_chars <> ''
    for xml path(''), type
  ).value('.', 'varchar(max)') as spec_chars
```

Comment: God! It is big query but I will check it it works :)

Comment: It really works! thanks! so I just add characters and replace function to add upper cases letters too ?

Comment: Most DB instances and varchar column as case-insensitive, but if yours is case-sensitive then you may add other letters or simply make `lower(name_column)`.