# Removing special characters in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL and just know basic insert, update, and delete syntax.

I have an excel file, that I imported into the SQL server, but somehow, it brought in weird symbols and characters.

When I checked the excel file ,cleared all formatting, and re-uploaded, it would still show up, not sure how to clean it up.

Is there an easy replace syntax that you can suggest for me to use to do a global cleanup?

Sample values inside the columns are:

```
Lisa┬áHettinger┬á┬áCherry┬áCreek┬áProp
Lisa┬áJ┬áHernandez
```

I would need to remove the weird `┬` and `á` characters.

Comment: Or just replace the special characters with a space?

Comment: What is character type of the source and your SQL column you are inserting into? Also, check your SQL database Collation settings.

Comment: in excel, the column type is set to general, and in SQL, the column is nvarchar(256)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT specific characters from column SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032517/select-specific-characters-from-column-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you have are the "┬á" characters, you can try using the [REPLACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) command like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(N'Lisa┬áJ┬áHernandez', N'┬á', N' ')
```

I suspect the source code page has "┬á" as its space character.

**Update:** To update the values in the entire column, you can use

```
UPDATE [MyTableName] SET [MyColName] = REPLACE([MyColName], N'┬á', N' ');
```

Comment: ah, yes! Just the ┬á characters. By the way, is there a select replace I can do for a whole column, instead of targetting it to a specific value? Sorry, kinda just starting out here with more advanced SQL..

Comment: Hi Sir, thank you for that one, that solved my dilemma in removing the unwanted characters in my sql column, appreciate the fast help!